# multiple lines of rm in makefile failing

Tags: makefile, rm

I'm using the following Makefile for a kernel module, but I cannot get the `%Clean` target to work. The pattern matching is working correctly, and it prints out all of the `rm` commands, but only the first item in the list gets deleted. Any ideas?

```
obj-m := thunderfs.o         

build:     
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules     

%.o: $.c    
        $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules     

.PHONY: %Clean    
%Clean:     
    rm -f modules.order     
    rm -f Modules.symvers     
    rm -f $*.ko     
    rm -f $*.mod.c     
    rm -f $*.mod.o     
    rm -f $*.o
```

Here is the thunderfs.c file.  Issue `make build` or just `make`.

```
#include <linux/module.h>     
#include <linux/init.h>     
#include <linux/kernel.h>     

int init_mod(void) // Required to insmod     
{    
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello Cruel World\n");    
    return 0;    
}    

void clean_mod(void) // Required for rmmod     
{    
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Cruel World\n");    
}    

module_init(init_mod);    
module_exit(clean_mod);    

MODULE_AUTHOR("Matthew Carlis");    
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");    
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Starting fresh");
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Could you tell us which version of Make you're using, and post a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Using `%` in any target in a (GNU) makefile is dodgy; it is primarily used for general recipes.  Even if it works, I'd recommend against using it.  Obviously, one obvious alternative (workaround) is to put the argument lists of the various `rm` commands into a single one invocation.  That does not, however, explain the problem.

Comment: What do you type on the command line to invoke the `%Clean` target?  What gets put into the commands in place of the `$*` in lines such as `rm -f $*.mod.o`?